# Can we create different shape canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am not talking about creating different shapes in canvas i want to know whether it is possible to create canvas in different shapes or not.Your are thinking for what??? Let me explain.

In the image above ,there are 5 different canvas.how could we implement  this..
I know it could be a trick.But this is the question.
**What is the trick??**

Answer (score 0):

css shapes to style the out-line of the canvas

check this out
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border-radius:50px"></canvas>
```

Demo : 
http://jsfiddle.net/r24jsjjw/

Comment: ooo thanx... now i got this :) sorry i dont know why image is not displaying.

Comment: **A Caution:** When using CSS to reshape the canvas, keep in mind that *the canvas still has the same boundaries it had when it was rectangular*. This could allow the user to drag objects fully outside the visibly reshaped canvas and drop them outside. This will cause all outside shapes to be invisible & unreachable by the user.